# HTML textarea autotrim and other details

Tags: php, html, textarea, indentation, trim

Hi in my website users are allowed to upload text in a textarea which is later mailed to me and it is really important that it stays in its original shape. Meaning that all indents (space and tab) shall be there even if they are mistakes or incorrect. I also noticed that colored text (colored in Microsoft Word) also gets uncolored when it gets pasted in the textarea. Is it possible to manipulate the textarea in such a way so the text pasted on it stays exactly the same as it originally was?

Comment: There is no way to preserve the color.

Answer (score 0):

No, because HTML textareas support plain text only.  There are some third party plugins, such as [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), which will allow you to easily convert your textarea into a HTML editor.  (Your server will receive HTML code).  CKEditor even has a plugin to handle pastes from Microsoft Word.